# How to pass subscription name as parameter in YML passed to Azure PowerShell correctly?

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I trying to run the following PowerShell file from Azure DevOps YAML pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: sub_name # name of the subscription; required
  type: string 
  default: false

steps:
  - script: echo "Here is subscription name:" ${{ parameters.sub_name }}
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'Launching Main.yml'
    inputs:
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
      azureSubscription: My-SPN # This is my allmighty Service Principle
      ScriptType: 'FilePath'
      ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyPowerShell.ps1'
      ScriptArguments: -sub_name ${{ parameters.sub_name  }}
```

MyPowerShell.ps1 looks like this

```
$SID=(Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub_name).id
```

This errors saying:

##[error]Subscription AzureSubcription1 was not found in tenant . Please verify that the subscription exists in this tenant.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

But if I specify $sub_name as a variable inside the PowerShell like below

```
$sub_name=AzureSubcription1 
$SID=(Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub_name).id
```

it works fine without any errors.

In the documentation of the command it says:

```
    -SubscriptionId <System.String>
        Specifies the ID of the subscription to get.

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                None
        Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to run the same from my laptop with PowerShell 5 it works fine.
I tried to use Out-String -InputObject $sub_name didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I used (Get-AzContext).Subscription.id instead and it worked.